# Magento feature question is allowed here?

Tags: discussion

My question is can we ask question about if something can be achievalble with magento?

Or some functionality can we achieve using magento or we can use other platform or cms to achieve some functionality.

Because with magento client sometimes ask about functionality we generally don't aware of if this can be achievable with magento?

Because this is the place we can ask to magento community.

Answer (score 4):

First of all ask yourself what type of answer you would like to get. If your question will sound like "If I can do [this] with Magento?" the obvious answer will be "yes" or "no" which doesn't have much value for community.

My advice is before asking this type of questions try to make some research on your own and come up with at least some details of your research asking not if it is achievable but how is it achievable.

It will be also good practice to provide some details of what had you already tried. Maybe some code snippets. Otherwise it will look as you are asking the community to do your job for you.

Comment: I am not asking for code or anything i just ask if this type of question is allowed or not , if i ask this type of question then defiantly i came up with code or some research

Comment: in this case it is a good question.

Comment: Because I have one or two question of this type and I want to know if community is allowed that type of question ?

Comment: I would say that this is one of the reasons behind a deliberate Magento site on the SE network - questions such as these were regularly closed/deleted from SO. As long as the question shows evidence of thoughtful research prior to posting then it will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you *can't* do with Magento - in their own words, it is a "Platform for Growth".

It all depends on how much time you have, how big your budget is and how talented you are.

---

So if you ask if anything is possible, you're going to get of of 2 answers,

- Yes, natively
- Yes, but not natively

But this isn't really the place for theoretical questions, or where a question doesn't have a definitive answer.

I'm not really sure what kind of answer you are looking to get; a good Magento developer will tell you nothing is impossible - but they're not going to post all the code required to solve your issue.

Comment: Maybe point people to IRC or Magento Commerce forums, then? We should have something in the wiki about this.

Comment: But sometimes code is not important just right idea can   give you right direction to think oh this is the way I can do thing with magento. :)